# ABAP How to convert xml file to abap object automatically (like in java for example)

Tags: xml, oop, abap

I think that everything is in the title.
How can I convert xml to an abap Object ?

For example :
`<customers>
      <customer>
       <age>22</age>
    </customer>
    <customer>
       <age>56>/age>
    </customer>
</customers>`

```
CLASS customer definition.
PUBLIC SECTION.
data age type i.
ENDCLASS.
```

I've been through a lot of posts everywhere and did not get any answer.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: You can edit your original post with your supposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the interface `IF_SERIALIZABLE_OBJECT` [as documented](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenasxml_class_instances.htm).

Comment: Thanks. But from xml to an abap object, which "transformation" do you use ?

Comment: If you don't want to transform anything, use `id` - and read the documentation, that's also in there.